# Replace an entire coloumn in excel with a new value automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code which converts a given specific date format into a normal `Date`. Is there a way in which I can replace the entire column into my new date format may be by a button click or just using a function.

The code I have is:

```
Function CONVDATE(myDate) As Date

    Dim arr

    arr = Split(myDate)

    CONVDATE = arr(1) & " " & arr(2) & " " & arr(5) & " " & arr(3)

End Function
```

Comment: You can use a macro:  [A:A] = CONVDATE

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't work

Comment: I now see that the title of your question is different from what is in the body.  My response was directed to the title and placed a new VALUE in every cell in the column. If you want to process an "entire" column, you can write a macro which operates on every cell, and writes the result back into the cell.  But I am surprised you don't get a Type MisMatch error with your UDF.  What kind of inputs do you have?

Comment: So it is like this. I have a date format in a coloumn whics is

Fri Sep 12 00:00:00 EDT 2014

I used the above code to convert it into : 

9/12/14 12:00 AM

So now my question is to convert the non converted date's entire coloumn with the newly formatted date. I hope this makes it clear. This is the first time I am using macro and VBA. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Immediately to the right of your data enter:

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,11)&RIGHT(A1,4),"ddd mm dd yyyy")
```

and double-click the fill handle. Then select, Copy and Paste Special Values over the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a VBA solution, and you are happy with your CONVDATE function, you can use something like the following to convert an entire column:

===================================

```
Option Explicit
Sub CONVALLDATES()
    Dim RNG As Range, C As Range

'Next line may change depending on how your range to convert is set up
Set RNG = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

'Uncomment next line when debugged.
'application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each C In RNG
    With C
        .Value = CONVDATE(C)
        '.numberformat =  whatever format you want it displayed
    End With
Next C
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------
Function CONVDATE(myDate) As Date
    Dim arr
arr = Split(myDate)
CONVDATE = arr(1) & " " & arr(2) & " " & arr(5) & " " & arr(3)

End Function
```

====================================

You should add some error checking to ensure the string you are trying to convert is, indeed, in the specific format.